# AHK: Remove Text From String This Word To The First Line Break

Tags: string, search, clipboard, autohotkey

I work at a doctors office doing billing, and I've run into a problem. Because of an issue with the way the EMR (electronic medical record) program works, immunization codes don't always make it into the chart. In order to compensate for this, I have AHK also search for the name of the immunization (dangerous, I know). Just until recently, this was working fine, until one of the doctors canceled an order for an immunization. This threw a false positive because of the failsafe I included for the charts without the code (IMM94, and IMM97). I need to remove, from a very large string, everything after the word "CANCELED: " to the first line break that occurs after that word. I created a rather pretty string clipping function to do most of this kind of stuff, but it's taking issue with finding the line break because there are so many. The test case I'm working with is:

> Assessment and Plan:
>
> 1. Need for prophylactic vaccination and inoculation against influenza     (tab) CANCELED: Influenza, High Dose (65+) (newline)
> 2. Prediabetes     Work on weight loss and exercise
> 3. Osteopenia  Exercise and vit d and b 12

There's a lot of stuff both above this, and below this, but I want to extract ALL instances from my string of the word "CANCELED: " to the first line break after it.

This is what I'm trying, along with my function. It's not working, and in fact, it's duplicating the line beginning with "1. ":

```
^L::
lString := ClipBoard
If lString Contains Canceled
fString := ClipString(lString, "CANCELED: ", "`n")
Clipboard := fString
Return


ClipString(lString, aMarker, bMarker, Only := 0)
{ 
If (Only = 1)
Return SubStr(SubStr(lString, 1, InStr(lString, bMarker)+StrLen(bMarker)-1), InStr(lString, aMarker))
Else
Return SubStr(lString, 1, InStr(lString, aMarker)-StrLen(aMarker)) . SubStr(lString, InStr(lString, bMarker)+StrLen(bMarker))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strips "cancelled:" and any text following it from each line in clipboard

**Program:**

```
Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "im)\s*CANCELLED:.*\R?", "`r`n")
```

**Sample Input:**

```
alpha
beta cancelled: ABC asldkfalsd 
delta
gamma omega CANCELLed: zeta
theta
```

**Sample Output:**

```
alpha
beta 
delta
gamma omega 
theta
```

Comment: you might want to change `\`r\`n` to `\`r` depending on your operating system's default end of line character sequence (e.g., `\`r\`n` for windows, `\`n` for *nix)

Comment: Please do not post bare code, also provide an explanation for what the code is doing.

Comment: @JonathanMee My code was commented though. My answer was anyway. (I figured commenting broken code wasn't all too helpful as I described what I was trying to do in the question.)

Comment: @DarknessCalling My comment was addressed at Jim U's bare code answer. You seem to be claiming Jim U's code in a way that leads me to fear that you are [Legion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mass_Effect_characters#Legion)

Comment: I added `?` to the regex so the last line of the clipboard will be processed even without an end-of-line character. `\s*` added to strip whitespace preceding any matches

Comment: @JimU Dang, so my code is needlessly over complicated? I was really proud of it...

Comment: @JimU I'm trying to make it dynamic, and "Return RegExReplace(lString, "im)\s*aMarker*\R?", bMarker)" doesn't seem to work. aMarker and bMarker are variables, but what I found on a forum seems to show that I don't need %s or anything. It did have a slightly different arrangement of quotes, but AHK had a fit when I tried to mimic it. Help?

Comment: @JimU Nevermind! Figured it out. The RegExReplace page on AutoHotKey.com is really dense and hard to understand, but with a little bit of trial and error, I got it. It's "Return RegExReplace(lString, "im)\s*"(aMarker)".*\R?", bMarker)" If that's not right, let me know, but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out. I'll comment it to help anyone who has this issue. I love how compact you can get functions usually, but this piece really needed a couple more lines than I'd like. If anyone can get it down to less, and have it still work, let me know!

```
^L::
ClipBoard := ClipString(ClipBoard, "Canceled: ", "`n",2) ;This is the function call here.
;The first parameter is the string to do stuff to, the second is what to cut out of the 
;string, and the third parameter is how far after that piece to cut, so if you wrote 
;Canceled: thenawholebunchofstuffthena newline, it'd remove all of it except for the 
;newline. The third parameter is which mode to put ClipString to.
Return


ClipString(lString, aMarker, bMarker, Mode := 0) ;already explained above. 
;Mode defaults to zero because I call the zero mode a lot.
{ 
If (Mode = 0) ;Mode Zero returns the ONLY the section from the original string 
;between aMarker and bMarker.
    Return SubStr(lString, 1, InStr(lString, aMarker)-StrLen(aMarker)) . SubStr(lString, InStr(lString, bMarker)+StrLen(bMarker))
Else If (Mode = 1) ;Mode One returns the original string with the section between aMarker 
;and bMarker removed.
    Return SubStr(SubStr(lString, 1, InStr(lString, bMarker)+StrLen(bMarker)-1), InStr(lString, aMarker))
Else If (Mode = 2) ;Mode Two returns the original string with all instances of aMarker 
;to bMarker removed. I.E. Every occurrence of aMarker will be removed to bMarker.
    {
    aString := lString
    StringReplace, aString, aString, %aMarker%, %aMarker%, UseErrorLevel ;Count how many 
;instances of aMarker are in the original string.
    CanCnt := Errorlevel ;actual count of # of aMarkers
    Loop, %CanCnt% ;loop as many times as there are aMarkers
        {
        aString := SubStr(aString, 1, InStr(aString, aMarker)-1) . SubStr(SubStr(aString, InStr(aString, aMarker)), InStr(SubStr(aString, InStr(aString, aMarker)), bMarker)-1) 
;this is a tad complicated. The first part before the concatenate takes the string, and
;keeps from the start point to the first aMarker. The concatenate adds the substring of the 
;substring between aMarker and the end of the string, and the location of the substring in 
;aString from the occurrence of aMarker to one position before the start of bMarker. 
;An easier way to read this would be to replace "SubStr(aString, InStr(aString, aMarker)) 
;with a variable like bString. It shortens it up quite a bit.
        }
    Return aString
    }
}
```